# How to go through a 2D array and find the index of specific sequence?

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, 2d

I am trying to go through a 2D array and find the longest period in which temperatures are above a given K temperature.

For example:
Input
11 10 30 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
**34 34** 30 10 **34 34** 10 10 10 10
**35 35 35** 3 **35** **35** 3 3 3 3 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 39 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
3 3 3 3 3 3 **35 35 35 35**

Output:
11

Where:
11 is the number of rows (count of settlements)
10 is the number of columns (count of days)
30 is the limited temperature

And If there is more than one solution, the output should be the smallest index. If there is no solution output must be -1.

Getting the data and storing them in the array, is working fine. But I am having trouble setting up the condition.

Using this code, is giving me the number 3 back.

I apologise if this is the wrong format to ask a question, I am pretty new to coding.

```
using System;
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        int cntSettlements = Convert.ToInt32(input.Split(" ")[0]);
        int cntDay = Convert.ToInt32(input.Split(" ")[1]);
        int tempLimit = Convert.ToInt32(input.Split(" ")[2]);

        int[,] dataIn = new int[cntSettlements, cntDay];

        for (int i = 0; i < cntSettlements; i++)
        {
            string input1 = Console.ReadLine();

            for (int j = 0; j < cntDay; j++)
            {
                dataIn[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(input1.Split(" ")[j]);
            }
        }

        int longestTempAboveLimitCount = 0;
        int longestTempAboveLimitRowIndex = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < cntSettlements; i++)
        {
            int currentTempAboveLimitCount = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < cntDay; j++)
            { 
                if (dataIn[i, j] > tempLimit)
                {
                    currentTempAboveLimitCount++;
                }
            }
            if (currentTempAboveLimitCount > longestTempAboveLimitCount)
            {
                longestTempAboveLimitCount = currentTempAboveLimitCount;
                longestTempAboveLimitRowIndex = i + 1;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(longestTempAboveLimitRowIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is below, but I have to comment on the way you asked the question. Always try to condense the question, by making sure you have narrowed down your problem. Sometimes the solution will just pop by itself if you try to express the problem in plain language. The problem was in the ```longestPeriod()``` method, so that's the only code snippet you should have posted, along with an input/output example. You could have even omitted that example all together if you had just said - I need to find the index of the row which has the most column values satisfying a certain condition.

Comment: And be consistent when naming things. Look here ```public static int[,] readData(int length, int cnt)```, the ```length``` and ```cnt``` are misleading names if you use ```cntSettlements```, ```cntDay``` terminology in the rest of your code. Capital letters for method names in C# please. And that's it from me. All the best! :))

Comment: Thank you so much, I will definitely take your advices! It was very helpful :)

Comment: I think, the comparing and adjusting the current maximum code should be inside the for loop, right?

Comment: Well it is inside the outer for loop. The one that iterates through rows.

Comment: For some reason, my code is failing some test, but passing some and I am a little confused. I just tried both and saw that both ways don't play a role at all.

Comment: Edit the question with input/output pairs that confuse you.

Comment: Just did, and I also replaced the code.

Comment: I just tested. What you said is not true. For code and input you provided, output is 3.

Comment: I said that up there :)

Comment: 3 is the right output, as 3rd row has more above the limit values (5) than 11th row (4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
//current maximum and index of current maximum
int longestTempAboveLimitCount = 0;       
int longestTempAboveLimitRowIndex = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < cntSettlements; i++)  
{
   //current row counter
   int  currentTempAboveLimitCount = 0;   

   for (int j = 0; j < cntDay; j++)
   {
      //criterium
      if (data[i, j] > limitemp)          
      {
         currentTempAboveLimitCount++;
      }
   }
   
   //comparing and adjusting the current maximum
   if (currentTempAboveLimitCount > longestTempAboveLimitCount)  
   {
      longestTempAboveLimitCount = currentTempAboveLimitCount;
      longestTempAboveLimitRowIndex = i;
   }
}

Console.WriteLine(longestTempAboveLimitRowIndex);
```